# SSL_connect returns SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and ERR_get_error gives zero always

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

I am trying to build a `ssl` client and testing it with `s_server` provided by  `openssl`. Until socket's connection, everything is fine but `SSL_connect()` fails and returns `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

> **SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:** Some I/O error occurred. The OpenSSL error queue may contain more information on the error. If the error queue is empty (i.e. ERR_get_error() returns 0), ret can be used to find out more about the error: If ret == 0, an EOF was observed that violates the protocol. If ret == -1, the underlying BIO reported an I/O error (for socket I/O on Unix systems, consult errno for details).

As documentation states, I further diagnosed with `ERR_get_error()` and it returned `0`. How can I look `errno` in windows? On other side, server also doesn't show a lot.

```
D:\server>openssl s_server -accept 5555 -cert server.crt -key server.key -msg -debug  
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
read from 0x600077c90 [0x600096e40] (11 bytes => 0 (0x0))
ERROR
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

**EDIT** Today I tried to print error string

```
err = SSL_connect(ssl);
ERR_error_string(SSL_get_error(ssl, err), buf);
printf("Error: %s\n", buf);
```

and the output was

```
Error: error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib
```

Which looks like something with `Diffie-Hellman` problem. there is another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479376/openssl-ssl-accept-error-5) about `dH` parameters but as they mentioned, I am not setting `dh` parameters myself.

Other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525344/ssl-connect-and-ssl-error-syscall) talk about `ssl` version. I have also tried their suggestions but doesn't help.

**Environment:** I am on Windows, gcc (cygwin) compiler, `openssl-1.02k`

I also tried with `errno` but it returns `No Error`

```
case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
    perror(errno);
    break;
```

Complete code from client is

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ON      1
#define OFF     0
#define RETURN_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(1); }
#define RETURN_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
int sock_conn;
SSL_CTX *ctx;
#define DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE 64
void handle_error(const char *file, int lineno, const char *msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "** %s:%i %s\n", file, lineno, msg);
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  exit(1);
}

void Errors_SSL(const char * file, int line)
{
    char *buf;
    unsigned long code;
    code = ERR_get_error();
    while (code)
    {
        ERR_error_string(code, buf);
        printf(buf);
        printf("error code: %lu in %s line %d.\n", code, file, line);
        code = ERR_get_error();
    }
}

#define ssl_error() Errors_SSL( __FILE__, __LINE__)

#define int_error(msg) handle_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)

void die(const char *msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(1);
}

int startTCPConnection()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0 )
        int_error("socket() fails");
    
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    
    memset (&server_addr, '\0', sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(5555);       /* Server Port number */
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); /* Server IP */
 
    if ( connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0 )
        int_error("connect() fails");
    
    printf("TCP Socket Connected\n");
    return sock; 
}

SSL_CTX *createSSLObject()
{
    int verify_client = OFF;
    SSL_CTX *ct = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    if (ct == NULL)
        int_error("SSL_CTX_new() returned 0");
    
    if(verify_client == ON)
    {
        /* Load the client certificate into the SSL_CTX structure */
        if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ct, "device.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) 
        {
           ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
           exit(1);
        }
 
        /* Load the private-key corresponding to the client certificate */
        if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ct, "device.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) 
        {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            exit(1);
        }
 
        /* Check if the client certificate and private-key matches */
        if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ct)) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Private key does not match the certificate public key\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
 
    //SSL_CTX_set_mode(ct, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    
    if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ct, "rootCA.pem", NULL))
        int_error("SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() failed");
    
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ct, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ct,2);
    
    return ct;
}

int main()
{
    int err, e;
    char    hello[80];
    //printf ("Message to be sent to the SSL server: ");
    //fgets (hello, 80, stdin);
    
    SSL_library_init(); // load all cipher and crypto algorithms
    SSL_load_error_strings();  // error strings for libssl
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();    
    ERR_load_crypto_strings(); // error strings for libcrypto

    ctx = createSSLObject();
    sock_conn = startTCPConnection();
    
    SSL * ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    RETURN_NULL(ssl);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock_conn);
    SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
    
    do 
    {
        err = SSL_connect(ssl);
        if (err < 0)
        {
            switch (SSL_get_error(ssl, err))
            {
                case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_NONE");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ: 
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ\n");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE\n");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT: case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT || SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT\n");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                    do
                    {
                        e = ERR_get_error();
                        if (e > 0)
                            int_error("Error");
                    }while (e > 0);
                     
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL\n");
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                    printf("SSL_ERROR_SSL");
                    break; 
                default:
                    break;       
            }
            //ERR_clear_error();
        }
    }while(SSL_is_init_finished(ssl) == 0);   
    
    printf ("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher (ssl));
    
    X509  *server_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate (ssl);    
    if (server_cert != NULL)
    {
        printf ("Server certificate:\n");
        char *str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(server_cert),0,0);
        printf ("\t subject: %s\n", str);
        free (str);
        str = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(server_cert),0,0);
        printf ("\t issuer: %s\n", str);
        free(str);
        X509_free (server_cert);
    }
 

    return 0;
}
```

A long time ago I got this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259683/ssl-accept-fails-with-return-value-1) and could not got any solution and never worked again due to time issue.

Note: I have also tried many off the shelf tutorial client examples from other people and all of them fails on `connect`. There is another non blocking socket [solution](https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca), that works fine for me but I want to dig out why a blocking socket is failing.

Comment: The code works for me on linux with OpenSSL 1.0.2l. It is unknown which OpenSSL version you are using. Also, your debug output is not complete, i.e. it is missing among other the exact bytes received. Could you please provide the complete and unchanged debug output from the server?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am using `openssl-1.02k`, also edited in the question now. thanks

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't change anything from server output. if I add `-state` switch, it also prints `SSL_accept:before/accept initialization` but nothing else, I have copy pasted, believe me. It works on unix? strange.

Comment: I see - your server is trying to read 11 bytes but gets only 0, i.e. seemingly the client closed the connection. Are you really running this code on 127.0.0.1 only as shown in the code? Since it works perfectly on Linux I could imaging that there is some Antivirus or similar involved which tries to infer with connections.

Comment: Yes, it is localhost. it is real code what I am running without a bit change.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich as I mentioned in my question that I have setup another setup where I have non blocking sockets and there it works. But that is server rather.

Comment: All I can say is that according to the servers debug output it gets a successful TCP connection from the client (`ACCEPT`) but then it fails to read any data from the client (`11 bytes => 0 (0x0)`) which makes it look like the client has closed the connection. And that it works for me unchanged on Linux so that I assume that it is ether a problem specific to Windows or your specific setup.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich `ACCEPT` is before the connection. Server shows this even before I have not initiated client request.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Today I got more detailed error on client side `Error: error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib` may be you have idea. I have edited question also for detail.

Comment: On Windows you need to look at `WSAGetLastError()`.

Comment: @EJP I am using `gcc` compiler provided by `Cygwin`. I have `sockets` not `winsock`.

Comment: So you need to lok at `errno`, as you were told originally, and your question abot how to do so on Windows was futile.

Comment: @EJP `errno` doesn't give anything.

Comment: @EJP I mentioned already in my question that I have `gcc` but compiling for windows.

Comment: @EJP I called `perror(errno);` directly after `case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:` and it returned `No Error`

Comment: Maybe related: [SSL_accept() fails with return value -1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44259683/608639).

Comment: @jww already linked to the question.

Comment: @GulluButt - Take this with a grain of salt, but MinGW and Cygwin pretty much sucks. They are good solutions, but I think they solve the wrong problem. Its a bad idea to try "Linux on Windows". When on Windows, do as Windows does. Conversely, when on Linux, do as Linux does and don't use Mono. Maybe you should setup a Linux VM using Virtual Box, and then do native Linux development. You will avoid all the Cygwin and OpenSSL bugs related to pretending to be Linux on Windows.

Comment: @jww I would give +1 because, after struggling with mingw  and Cygwin, I have the same impression. I post almost similar question 3 months ago but still the problem is there. I have to seriously think about this cross compiling I guess.

Comment: @jww frankly speaking, I hate visual studio ide, it is like a big crane for collecting stones. I like to work with makefiles and use compiler from cmd. I have to look how to do it. I always worked with gcc but on Linux.